# Is this element algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm trying to see whether the following element is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and if it is - try and find its degree:

$$ a = \left(\frac{(1 + \sqrt[3]{7})^{7/5}}{(\sqrt[3]{7} - 7)^3 + 77}\right)^{13} $$

I don't really have an idea where to begin - so what I did was typing that into WolframAlpha:

[Result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal%20polynomial%20(((1%20%2B%207%5E%7B1%2F3%7D)%5E%7B7%2F5%7D)%2F((7%5E%7B1%2F3%7D%20-%207)%5E3%20%2B%2077))%5E13)

So it seems that the degree is 15 (and the answer is YES), but how do I check that?

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: The algebraic closure is a field.  If $a^{1/13}$ is a algebraic, then so is $a$.  Continuing in this way, you can check that the numerator and denominator are algebraic.

Comment: Note that $a \in \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}, \sqrt[5]{1+\sqrt[3]{7}})$. This field has degree $15$, hence $a$ is algebraic of degree $15$.

Comment: @Crostul Technically, this only proves that the degree of $a$ _divides_ $15$. There _could_ be smaller, intermediate fields that contains $a$. Not that I believe that that is the case.

Comment: @Crostul thank you. How do I compute that degree? Is it true that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}, \sqrt[5]{1 + \sqrt[3]{7}}): \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[5]{1 + \sqrt[3]{7}})) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})] [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}) : \mathbb{Q}]   $?

Edit: of course it's true. Sorry for the question

Answer (score 1):

Since $a^5=(1+\sqrt[3]{7})^{7\cdot 13} /((\sqrt[3]{7}-7)^3+77)^{5\cdot 13}$, it's clear that $a^5\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$.  Since the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, 3, is prime, there are no intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.  It follows that unless $a^5\in\mathbb{Q}$, $a^5$ will generate $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  But, working over the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_7$ of the 7-adic completion $\mathbb{Q}_7$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, we have
$$(1+\sqrt[3]{7})^{7\cdot 13}\equiv 1 \pmod 7$$
and
$$(\sqrt[3]{7}-7)^3+77\equiv 7\cdot5\cdot (1 - 2 (\sqrt[3]{7})^2) \pmod {7^2}$$
so
$$(5\cdot 7)^{5\cdot 13}a^5\equiv (1-2(\sqrt[3]{7})^2)^{-5\cdot 13}
\equiv 1+2\cdot 5\cdot 13(\sqrt[3]{7})^2
\pmod {7},
$$
which means that $a^5$ cannot be rational.

Now, $$\mathbb{Q}(a)=\mathbb{Q}(a,a^5)=\mathbb{Q}(a,\sqrt[3]{7})=\mathbb{Q}((1+\sqrt[3]{7})^{1/5},\sqrt[3]{7}),$$
so to verify that $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ has degree 15 over $\mathbb{Q}$, it will do to show that $(1+\sqrt[3]{7})^{1/5}$ has degree 5 over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$.  However, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$ can be embedded in the 2-adic completion $\mathbb{Q}_2$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, and then, since $1+\sqrt[3]{7}\equiv 8 \pmod {16}$, any root of $P(x):=x^5-(1+\sqrt[3]{7})$ in $\overline{ \mathbb{Q}}_2$ must have 2-adic valuation equal to $\frac{3}{5}$.  Therefore, $P(x)$ must be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ and then also over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$, completing the proof that $a$ has degree 15 over $\mathbb{Q}$.